# Ionic how to login by using WP Rest API

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

I have a Ionic Project for my wordpress site.

I use WP Rest API in my wordpress site.

I just want to know how to login in the app use wordpress user account.

Anybody could tell me more detail about how to do it...thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Here are many Solutions provded by google

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762

http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-api/

All in all everything depends on what plugin you use. If you really want to use WP REST API, then you will find something in these links.

We would also need to know why you need to login - maybe it's not even needed.

As you might notice the implementation depends on what plugin you use.